# Creating a Main Search Form on an Access Subform with nested Subforms

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a form - EmployeeDataForm - with multiple subforms - LockerSubForm, CurrentAssignmentSubForm, etc. - separated into different pages on a tab control.

Exactly following the instructions from this video: 
https://youtu.be/N0X8Hg-Sm6A 
I created an additional form - Employee Search and added EmployeeDataForm as a subform.

Now pulling up the Employee Search form automatically shows all records as expected. But entering anything into the Search bar and search depopulates all the fields.

This is my code

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "SELECT [Current Employee].[Last Name], [Current Employee].[First Name], " _
    & "[Current Employee].[Employee ID], [Current Employee].[Badge ID#], [Current Employee].Email, " _
    & "[Current Employee].DOB, [Current Employee].Insurance, [Current Employee].[Health Assessment], " _
    & "[Current Employee].[TX Zone], [Current Employee].[Hire Date], [Current Employee].Shirts, " _
    & "[Current Employee].Pants, [Current Employee].Jackets " _
    & "FROM [Current Employee] " _
    & "WHERE [Last Name] = '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*' " _
    & "ORDER BY [Current Employee].[Last Name];"

    Me.subEmployeeData.Form.RecordSource = SQL

    Me.subEmployeeData.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of setting RecordSource, I prefer to set Filter and FilterOn properties. When using wildcard in parameter, use LIKE instead of = sign.

Comment: This was exactly it. I feel so dumb to have missed it. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful here...this is wide open to sql injection. Not sure why you have this tagged with sql server as it seems to be 100% an Access situation.

Comment: I must have misread or fat fingered it while trying to hit sql query. My bad!